# Deleteing Tournaments in scidvspc

Tags: scid, scidb

I have imported several twic zip files into scid which gave a lot of "illegal move" error messages.  For obvious reasons, the vast majority of them are in "Rapid", "Blitz", and "Chess960" tournaments.  I would like to delete all of those tournaments.  The process I came up with is"

```
1. Open the tournament window.
2. Click on a tournament.
3. In the Crosstable window, click on the number of games.
4. In the Maintenance window, click on "Delete filter games".
5. Compact database.
6. Rinse, lather, repeat.
```

The above method is cumbersome since there are about 200 tournaments with the word "Rapid" in it.  My question: Is there an easier way to get all the games that have "Rapid" in the Event name into the filtered Game List window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I poke around enough, I will eventually find an answer.  In the "General" search screen, there is an Event field.  However, there appears to be a limit on how many games you can search.  In a database with over 1 million games, there were still "Rapid" games in the database even the "General" filter wasn't showing any.  Although the tournament screen was still showing some "Rapid" tournaments.